# Git LFS repo in GitLab with Artifactory LFS storage issue

Tags: git, gitlab, artifactory, git-lfs

My company has decreed that our GitLab instance caps repo size at 5G (including LFS), so for repos above 5G I am attempting to use our Artifactory instance as the LFS storage.  The Artifactory (LFS) portion seems to work great, but GitLab pre-receive hook blocks the push stating it did not receive the objects (which it will not, of course).  I'm just not sure how to get GitLab *not* to expect the objects.

1. I followed the official guide ([jfrog-link](https://jfrog.com/help/r/how-to-make-git-lfs-work-and-configure-it-with-artifactory-in-5-min/step-by-step-guide)) on adding the ".lfsconfig" option to the repo.
2. The Artifactory instance **does** receive the LFS data when I commit and push.
3. The issue is the GitLab server rejects the push expecting to receive the LFS objects.

Here is the error I see:

```
$ git push origin main
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (1/1), 12 KB | 0 B/s, done.
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 48 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 392 bytes | 130.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: GitLab: LFS objects are missing. Ensure LFS is properly set up or try a manual "git lfs push --all".
To ssh://gitlab.server:port/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://gitlab.server:port/repo.git'
```

Using the recommended "git lfs push ..." commands results in no error, but no actual push of the non-LFS data (i.e. it essentially does nothing).

For reference, I am just trying to test with a single zip archive.  Here are my .gitattributes and .lfsconfig files, respectively:

```
*.zip filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

```
[lfs]
url = "https://git-lfs:<access-token>@artifactory-server/artifactory/api/lfs/git-lfs"
```

As I mentioned, the Artifactory side of it seems to work perfectly.  It's just that pesky GitLab hook that is breaking the push.  I did try to uncheck the LFS flag in the repo in GitLab, but it seemed to have no effect.  Additionally, it should be noted I do not have admin access on the server side (can't mess with those hooks).

Thanks in advance for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my own question:

I said in my post that "I did try to uncheck the LFS flag in the repo in GitLab, but it seemed to have no effect"  That was *not* completely true.  I unchecked the flag but did not "Save changes".  When I unchecked the flag and saved changes future pushes worked just fine.

So I'll admit my stupidity here just in case somebody else in the future needs the advice. =P